# Does any subset of a finitely generated group with positive upper density contain three points in arithmetic progression?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, additive-combinatorics

Let $G$ be a countable finitely generated group, with word metric $d_S$ induced by some generating set $S$. Let $B_r$ be the ball of radius $r$ around the identity under $d_S$.

We say that $A \subset G$ has **positive upper density** if $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{|A\cap B_n|}{|B_n|}>0$ for some, hence any word metric $d_S$.

> **Question:** For any $A\subset G$ with positive upper density, does it hold that there exists some $a \in A$, and nonzero $g \in G$ such that $a, a + g, a + 2g$ are in $A$?

**Edit:** The original question asked about abelian groups, which is answered in the positive by Roth’s theorem as stated by Sean Eberhard in the comments.

Comment: Since $G$ is abelian and finitely generated, $G \cong \mathbf{Z}^r \times T$ for some finite group $T$. By passing to an appropriate coset you can reduce to $G = \mathbf{Z}^r$, so this reduces to Roth's theorem in a usual form. The question is more interesting if you drop the word abelian.

Comment: Note that a counterexample is easy for monoids.  Specifically, let $G$ be a free monoid with three generators $x,y,z$, and let $A$ be the set of all elements of $G$ that do not end with any word of the form $w^2$ for nontrivial $w\in G$.  Observe that only $1/3$ of words end in $xx$, $yy$, or $zz$, only $1/9$ of words end in $w^2$ for $|w|=2$, and so on, and since $1/3 + 1/9 + \cdots < 1$ the elements of $A$ have positive density in $G$.

Comment: Is it that clear that positive upper density is independent of the choice of finite generating subset?

Comment: What is $a+2b$ if $a,b$ do not commute?

Comment: @Ycor Yes, due to bilipschitzness (with respect to the different metrics) of the identity map.

Comment: @Matk Sapir $ab^2$.

Comment: @NateRiver sorry but I'm aware of bilipschitzness but then? if $B_n,B'_n$ is the $n$-ball with respect to two metrics, $B_n\cap B'_n$ can be negligible in $B_n$ and/or $B'_n$. Just take $G=F_2$, $B_n$ the standard $n$-ball, and $B'_n$ the standard $2n$-ball, which equals the $n$-ball for $B'_1=B_2$.

Comment: @YCor Oh, you may be right.. it would scale nonlinearly with C…

Answer (score 3):

I hope this might be of interest, I'll consider a simpler problem and present a couple $(G,A)$ where one can't find a progression of length four: $a, ag, ag^2, ag^3$.

Example. Let $G$ be the free group $F_2$ on $2$ generators with generating set $x_1, x_1^{-1}, x_2, x_2^{-1}$. Take $A$ as the union of all words of length $\varphi(n)=4^n$ for $n\ge 2$. It is easy to see that $A$ has positive upper density. However one can not find elements $a, ag, ag^2,ag^3\in A$ with $g\ne 1$. The reason here is the following.

**Observation.** Fix $a$ and $g$ and  consider the sequence of words $\ldots, ag^{-1},a,ag,\ldots, ag^n,\ldots$. Let $l(n)$ be equal to the length of $ag^n$. Then $l(n)$ is given by formula $d|n-x|+b$, where $d>0$, $x$ a fixed (half integer) number $b\ge 0$.

I don't want to write a complete proof of this observation. But the idea is that the multiplication by $g$ is acting by isometry of the Cayley graph of $F_2$ and it sends a unique geodesic (in the graph) to itself, and points $ag^{-n}$ are on the same distance to this geodesic (maybe there is a more obvious reasoning).

From this observation it is very easy to deduce the claim. Consider for example the case when $l(a)=l(ag)<l(ag^2)<l(ag^3)$. Suppose by contradiction these elements are all in $A$. In this case distance in the Cayley graph between $a$ and $ag$ is at most $2\cdot 4^n$ for some $n$. But the distance between $ag$ and $ag^2$ is at least $3\cdot 4^{n}$, a contradiction (the distance should be the same). Other cases are similar.

Comment: Minor remark: both a and b have multiple meanings in your answer. Actually, I think you never use the names of the generators.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, you are right, I'll rename them. I implicitly use them when I say that the density is positive. In fact, after thinking a bit about the remark of Ycor I am not sure that positivity of such density is independent of  the choice of generators. Maybe it is not in case when the growth of the group is exponential.